# Where to get Darwin installation media?

Tags: download, darwin

I want to play with Apple's Darwin, but it seems like they removed any download option and compiling from source doesn't sound very easy given that I don't have a Mac.

I just want the Base Darwin System with opensource tools which are the same as in the Mac.

I don't care about Linux distributions with Darwin kernels and most of them are dead in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org/) is active and being maintained and appears to pick up where OpenDarwin left off.  They have a downloadable ISO you can use to install the system. If you are looking specifically for the Mac tools check out the [Apple Open Source Releases](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) page.